# Is it normal to get this error while testing in app purchases for android?

Tags: react-native

Using react-native-iap everything seems to be working well except for this warning that I receive saying possible unhandled promise rejection: google is indicating that we have sime issue connecting to payment.
I am not sure if this appears only in test iap and will be solved when using real purchases.
[image]
the iap code is:

```
     useEffect(() => {
RNIap.initConnection()
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  .then(() => {
    RNIap.getSubscriptions(items)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response);
        setProduct(response);
      });

    RNIap.getAvailablePurchases()
      .catch(() => {})
      .then((response) => {
        try {
          console.log('purchases', response);
          const receipt = response[response.length - 1].transactionReceipt;
          if (receipt) {
            //  validate(receipt);
          }
        } catch (err) {}
      });
  });

purchaseErrorSubscription = RNIap.purchaseErrorListener((error) => {
  if (!(error['responseCode'] === '2')) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Error',
      'There has been an error with your purchase, error code' +
        error['code'],
    );
  }
});
purchaseUpdateSubscription = RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener(
  async (purchase) => {
    const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
    if (receipt) {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        validate(receipt);
        await updateSubscription({
          subscription: 'Subscribed',
          date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS'),
        })(dispatch, state);
        await RNIap.acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
        await RNIap.consumePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
        RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, false);
      } else if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
        validateIos(receipt);
        await updateSubscription({
          subscription: 'Subscribed',
          date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS'),
        })(dispatch, state);
        await RNIap.finishTransactionIOS(purchase.transactionId);
      }
    } else {
      await RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, true);
      await RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, false);
    }
  },
);

return () => {
  try {
    purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
  } catch (error) {}
  try {
    purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
  } catch (error) {}
  try {
    RNIap.endConnection();
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

}, []);

Comment: have you find any solution for this error..?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your backend function for your Google Authentication is working properly, and also check the validate receipt function. You can find 'how fetching that function' and sending' here.

```
const validate = async (receipt) => {
  const receiptBody = {
    productId: JSON.parse(receipt)['productId'],
    purchaseToken: JSON.parse(receipt)['purchaseToken'],
  };
  console.log('reciept body=======', receiptBody);

  try {
    await fetch(
      URL,
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: receiptBody }),
      },
    ).then((res) => {
      res.json().then((r) => {
        console.log('r======', r);
        setChecking(false);
        if (r.result.error == -1) {
          Alert.alert('Oops!', 'There is something wrong with your purchase');
        } else if (r.result.isActiveSubscription) {
          setPurchased(true);
        } else {
          Alert.alert(
            'Expired',
            'Your subscription has expired. Please subscribe.',
          );
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Alert.alert("Error!", error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify the explanation? The last sentence is confusing to me.